# wrong number of arguments (3 for 2) in form_for method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm upgraded to rails 3.2.13 and I'm migrating an old app to run in the new environment (ruby1.9.3).  The app ran fine with ruby192 and rails 3.0.0.

I was receiving this error when trying to create a new record (a firefighter)

wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)

And here was my code for my form

```
<%= form_for :fire_fighter, @fire_fighter, :url => { :action => "create" } do |f| %>
```

based on reading other posts, they recommend to remove "fire_fighter" but so it would look like this

```
<%= form_for :@fire_fighter, :url => { :action => "create" } do |f| %>
```

This did actually allow the page to render but when I tried to enter fill in the text fields and submit or create the record in the database I get an error message that is built into the app that says:[image: That the fields were all left blank]

All of the fields are setup as strings.

Oh and obviously i had all this fields filled out before I hit submit.  So now I'm just stuck.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although this answer may change when you post your page source code and the rest of the form code, you are trying to create a symbol from an instance variable.

```
<%= form_for :@fire_fighter, :url => { :action => "create" } do |f| %>
```

Notice `:@fire_fighter`. It really should be `@fire_fighter`. The correct code should then be

```
<%= form_for @fire_fighter, :url => { :action => "create" } do |f| %>
```

The reason why you use an instance variable like `@fire_fighter` is because in your controller there should be something like

```
def new
  @fire_fighter = FireFighter.new
end
```

that way, the form is directly grabbing the instance variable from the controller onto the form. Symbols don't transverse from controllers to views, but instance variables do, hence the use of `@fire_fighter` as the first argument in the `form_for` method.